# Problem with using "root.attributes('-type', 'splash')" in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

## Problem

My problem is that I want to make a custom title bar for my Tkinter app. I didn't want to use `root.overrideredirect(True)` because it removes the app from the taskbar. So I decided to use `root.attributes('-type', 'splash')` but when I run the app i get this error:
`_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm attributes window ?-alpha ?double?? ?-transparentcolor ?color?? ?-disabled ?bool?? ?-fullscreen ?bool?? ?-toolwindow ?bool?? ?-topmost ?bool??"`

## Code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook, Style, Separator

# root of app
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
root.attributes('-type', 'splash')

# style
style = Style()
# background color of separator
style.configure("Line.TSeparator", background="#2C313A")

# icons
icon = PhotoImage(file="icon.png")
menu_icon = PhotoImage(file="menu.png")
close_icon = PhotoImage(file="close.png")
maximize_icon = PhotoImage(file="maximize.png")
minimize_icon = PhotoImage(file="minimize.png")
restore_icon = PhotoImage(file="restore.png")

# make a frame for the title bar
title_bar = Frame(root, bg='#21252B', bd=0)
title_bar.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, height=45)

# Close button for title bar
close_button = Button(title_bar, bg='#21252B', bd=0, image=close_icon, command=root.destroy)
close_button.place(relx=0.95, rely=0.35)

# Maximize button for title bar
max_button = Button(title_bar, bg='#21252B', bd=0, image=maximize_icon, command=root.destroy)
max_button.place(relx=0.9, rely=0.275)

# Restore button for title bar
restore_button = Button(title_bar, bg='#21252B', bd=0, image=restore_icon, command=root.destroy)

# Minimize button for title bar
min_button = Button(title_bar, bg='#21252B', bd=0, image=minimize_icon, command=root.destroy)
min_button.place(relx=0.85, rely=0.275)

# Icon for title bar
title_bar_icon = Label(title_bar, image=icon, bg='#21252B')
title_bar_icon.pack(side=LEFT)

# bottom separator for title bar
title_bar_separator = Separator(root, orient="horizontal", style="Line.TSeparator")
title_bar_separator.place(relx=0, rely=0.075, relwidth=1)

root.mainloop()
```

## Full Error

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:/Users/User/Desktop/PythonProjects/SideDrawer/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\PythonProjects\SideDrawer\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    root.attributes('type', 'splash')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1976, in wm_attributes
    return self.tk.call(args)
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm attributes window ?-alpha ?double?? ?-transparentcolor ?color?? ?-disabled ?bool?? ?-fullscreen ?bool?? ?-toolwindow ?bool?? ?-topmost ?bool??"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So How do I fix this

Comment: it clearly means that there is no such attribute, You will have to somehow combine two windows so that one is withdrawn an the other has overrideredirect

Comment: You can try type `toolwindow`.

Comment: @Matiiss OP wants *a custom title bar*, not borderless window.

Comment: @acw1668 how would I use toolwindow attribute

Comment: just `root.attributes('-toolwindow', True)`

Comment: Try `root.attributes('-toolwindow', 1)`, but it still be removed from taskbar.

Comment: @acw1668 as far as I understand to create a __custom__ title bar You have to remove the border otherwise the bar will be in system color

Comment: @Matiiss I don't want to use tool window as there is still that ugly border it there another way to remove the title bar but still keep the app in the task bar

Comment: as I said You have to use `.overrideredierct()` but You also create another window and `.withdraw()` it. a bit complicated but there are answers on this I think (maybe)

Comment: You have to use `.iconify` actually instead of `.witdraw`

Comment: The reason why you get the error is that `.attributes('-type', ...)` only exists in Linux and you are using Windows. And anyway `root.attributes('-type', 'splash')` would not have solved your problem in Linux either since it also makes the app disappear from the taskbar.

Comment: @Zues I might be a bit late but look at [this for windows](https://github.com/TheLizzard/BetterTk/blob/main/src/bettertk/notitlebartk_win.py) and [this for linux](https://github.com/TheLizzard/BetterTk/blob/main/src/bettertk/notitlebartk_x11.py). I made that code so I might be able to help you if you don't understand the code.